# Should I use comma or not in "She left my room, smiling"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, commas, clauses, present-participles

Suppose a girl left my room and while leaving, she was smiling. Then which of the following should I use?

**1. She left my room smiling**.

Or

**2. She left my room, smiling**.

Should I use comma ? Actually adding a comma makes me think that first the girl smiled and then left my room and the time difference between two actions is very less and that's why I use present participle form rather than perfect participle. Please clear my confusion.

Comment: It depends what you are trying to say. If you have managed to cheer the girl up so that she arrived in tears but left the room smiling, you don't need a comma. If you are just saying that she left the room and happened to be smiling at the time, you can use the comma.

Comment: The first has the odd connotation that rooms can smile. It would probably vanish in a paragraph of context, but standing alone, there is no precedent for your brain to naturally attach to except the room itself. [A similar effect can be seen in the other two questions you asked today, which I'm finding in reverse order.]

Answer (score 2):

There is no way the first option can be misinterpreted, so a comma is unnecessary. Both options are fine.

That being said, the nuances Kate Bunting describes in [their comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/319456/should-i-use-comma-or-not/341319#comment600509_319456) still stand.

Answer (score 1):

While the use of commas is largely a matter of personal preference, in your example, you need a comma. It serves to indicate the obvious pause that's intended after **room**. It also makes it clear that **smiling** modifies **she** and not **room**.

The same indicated pause would be required if you reversed the sentence: **Smiling, she left the room.**

You would not require a comma if the sentence read: **She left the room upstairs**, where **upstairs** is being used as an adjective to describe the room.